# decode encrypted information on android

Tags: java, android, security, random

I'm trying to send some information from 1 web application to an android app, however the information has to be stored encrypted in the web application.
To this end I'm trying to use a Symmetric key to encrypt the data in my web application and use the same key to decrypt it in the app.

The following is my code to generate the encrypted data on the server:

```
String key = "someData";

    SecretKeySpec sks = null;
    try {
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed("exSeed".getBytes());
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kg.init(128, sr);
        sks = new SecretKeySpec((kg.generateKey()).getEncoded(), "AES");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    byte[] encodedBytes = null;
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
        encodedBytes = c.doFinal(key.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    jTextField5.setText(Base64.encode(encodedBytes));
```

And the following is my code to read the data in the app:

```
    SecretKeySpec sks = null;
    try {
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed("exSeed".getBytes());
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kg.init(128, sr);
        sks = new SecretKeySpec((kg.generateKey()).getEncoded(), "AES");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "AES secret key spec error");
    }

    byte[] decodedBytes = null;
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
        decodedBytes = c.doFinal(key);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "AES decryption error");
    }
    String decoded = new String(decodedBytes);
```

Now the problem I run into is that when decoding I get the following exception: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted

I suspect this is because the secureRandom does not generate the same number in a regular application and an android application (despite having the same seed). However I do not see a way to use another way to use secureRandom or a way to not use it.

Any help to get this working would be greatly appriciated, as would any comment about how secure this method of encryption is.

Comment: Have you tried specifically setting the method and padding after the encryption algorithm (AES). Get a Cipher instance like this Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding") in both the encryption and decryption.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't realy understand what you mean, I already use Cipher.getInstance("AES") right?

Comment: yeah, that's the algorithm but sometimes systems use different default methods  (ECB,CBC) and paddings (PKCS5Padding, NoPadding)... so setting these might solve your issue... if not then it's the key that is not the same (it has to be the same byte for byte)

Comment: Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES"); changed to Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"); in both encrypting and de crypting, still does not decode. Also checked the random seed, this is identical to. Still have the feeling that it has something to do with the random though, as when I encode and decode on the same machine (either on the phone or in the desktop application) it does work.

Comment: It could also be the SecureRandom class itself. The java.security.SecureRandom class does not implement a pseudo-random number generator. Instead it uses implementations found in other classes such as  sun.security.provider.SecureRandom and sun.security.provider.NativePRNG depending on the operating system being used. So try going with SUN SHA1PRNG on your encryption/decryption methods using this: SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");

Comment: The problem was indeed in SecureRandom itself, while SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN") did not work as andoird did not know SUN as a provider for random variables, it did point me in the right direction though. As after some more searching I found that I should not be using SecureRandom at all but rather MessageDigest to generate the seed. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was the SecureRandom, it did not use the same random number generator, and as I found out later should not be used for these purpouses anyhow. Instead I used MessageDigest which works perfectly.